# How does Google Analytics avoid Spoofing?

Tags: javascript, security, api, node.js

So I'm stuck trying to figure out how Google Analytics avoids spoofing. Sure, when you sign up for an account, they make you verify that you own the domain by uploading a file. But you are also given some script tags with a unique public code (replaced with 'XXXXXXX' below). What's stopping somebody from copying that code, spoofing the request headers, and pretending to be my site by following Google's authentication strategy with curl?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'XXXXXXX']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

The reason I ask is because I'm trying to create a similar JavaScript plugin that exposes my site's data to participating websites ("clients"). I'm not sure how I can get this functionality without a private key on the client's server side. That kind of sucks because I was really going for the whole "easy as Google Analytics to integrate". Any thoughts?

Comment: How would someone spoof your domain (with the file on it)? I mean I know it can be done, but I don't think somebody would go through all that trouble to serve stats. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: I've thought about this before but couldn't come up with a reason _why_ anyone would want to do it. The spoofer would just be inserting data into my stream, so what would they have to gain?

Comment: Not 100% clear on what you mean by "exposes your site's data to participating websites"?  Google Analytics captures data, yet your exposing it?  Can you please **edit** your question and clarify?

Comment: @freejosh I'm assuming Google has fixed this problem not because my website is important but because the integrity of all the websites using their analytics software is important.

However, the question is less related to Google and more related to security in this particular strategy. How do you prevent spoofing in this scenario?

Comment: @leahy16 You have told Google what domain to check didn't you?

Comment: @jmort253 I'm using Socket.IO to open a connection between my server and the session on the client's website. Before I do this, I want to make sure that the client's website is actually the client's website and not an impersonator.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa I'm not entirely sure what you mean but it's not about Google specifically. It's about how do you make sure a website is truly a website and not a spoofer who grabbed the public identifier and changed the request headers?

Comment: @leahy16 I think SSL and certificates would need to be involved to avoid spoofing. Is your data really that sensitive or can you just write this off as a risk? Also, are you even to that point where it's a concern? Do you have millions of users using your product? You might be thinking about something that, while important, might not be so necessary at this stage in the game.

Comment: @jmort253, what does SSL have to do with anything?  The API token is public, and I agree with the OP that it is a curious puzzle how spoofing can be prevented.

Comment: @leahy16 because you are going to make a request to that specific website and not the other way around. Basically you will have a mapping of `unique id` and address. When you receive a request to 'expose' data. Do not expose it by replying to that request, but rather use a new connection using the mapping you have.

Comment: @KirkWoll - If it's public, then how do you prevent it from being read via port 80 port listeners between client and server? If you're screaming out the password to the troll at the bridge for everyone else to hear, then they too can use that same, now unsecure password to cross said bridge. My point was that if you want to authenticate anything, you have to do so securely.

Comment: Also, Google analytics doesn't do anything to prevent other data from being recorded. Try it, just put your JS code on a little weebly website you stand up somewhere. You'll see the data. The only way to prevent that data from being written to GA is to use filters to filter it out. In the op's case, he's not receiving data, he's sharing it, which is the exact opposite of what Google Analytics is doing, which means he may be trying to protect his data from unauthorized access. My suggestion is to edit out all of the GA stuff from the question as it adds some confusion.

Comment: "exposes my site's data" could mean "exposes it to being modified," not necessarily "exposes it to being revealed." At least, that's how I interpreted that last bit. If it does mean the latter, then the question doesn't make much sense, I agree.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like this question really has nothing to do with Google Analytics (I'd really suggest you remove that from your question as I think it's misleading most people and not getting you closer to your answer).

You have some data and you want to share it with only select sites.  There is no other way to do that besides protecting the data with some sort of authorization scheme and then giving the selected sites some sort of password or key that lets them have access to it while others who you did not give the key to will not get access to the data.  Even this scheme would only work if the code accessing the data is in a private area on a server (where keys/passwords can be protected), not javascript in a browser.

As to the GA spoofing (which I don't think has anything to do with your real question), I suspect that Google doesn't worry about it much because other than a denial of service attack on GA in general (which I suspect they do have protection against), what benefit is there to recording hits for someone else's web site?  Whoever is doing it can't get access to the data because the data is in someone else's GA account.  I suppose one could do it as annoyance to someone to try to screw up their GA numbers, but without some more profitable motivation, there probably isn't a lot of people trying to do that.

Comment: Analytics information is important to many organisations. I think it's pretty obvious what you gain from recording fake analytics data against another website, just like any sort of vandalism attacks in any competitive market. In this case, you're denying your competitors a good access to valuable analytical insights that GA is supposed to provide, and/or steering them towards harms way with misleading data. This question is very relevant to GA because security mechanisms are very product/technology specific

Comment: I understand the question perfectly as I am looking for the exact same thing. Explain the authentication architecture behind services like google analytics. The example referrenced is very good in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question.

As the comments hint, Google doesn't really address this. In fact, it's common to have conditional code / preprocessing stuff to disable GA on your staging site / dev boxes, because if you don't it will screw up your numbers.

You could try a sort of three-legged approach with the analytics server, the customer server, and the client. It could work something like this:

- Customer's server and your analytics server share a secret key. When the client hits the customer's site, the customer's server tells your analytics server it wants to start tracking this particular customer.
- Your analytics server generates a session id for this user, and returns a dynamic URL to the customer's server. The URL points to your JavaScript tracking code (or a loader for it), injected with the session ID.
- The customer's server sends the page to the client. The page contains your client-side tracking code with the unique session ID. Actions are tracked and sent to your analytics server.
- On your analytics server, you receive tracking information from the client's machine. You check that the session ID is valid and not expired, and that the IP address matches.

This should provide an extra level of security. Unfortunately, it will not be "easy as Google Analytics to integrate..." it would involve server-side participation on the part of your customers. It also won't do as much good for tracking users who haven't been authenticated by your customers, because a third party could simply visit your customer's site to get a valid session ID and then send some fake info to your analytics server. However, for clients authenticated by your customer's site, it could be useful.

Good luck!

Comment: There is also [open web analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/), btw...